# Jmeter: Http POST request with body data and file upload

Tags: jmeter, postman, mime-types, load-testing, content-type

I'm trying to test a Rest api which is working on postman but not on Jmeter, 
the request takes (2 parameters):

- a pdf file
- a body data (json containing pdf information)

on Postman : when I put the Content-Type = application/x-www-form-urlencoded, and I upload the json file and the pdf file it works
but on jmeter I'm always getting errors such as "Unsupported Media Type"

Comment: have you found a solution for this? I am fighting with the same problem and no luck with Jmeter.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to add record the network request in Jmeter via postman. I have came across the below link which will do the trick for you

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OQWyLMJbXaw

The solution mentioned in the above link actually uses a proxy server in Postman and use the same proxy server in Jmeter test script recorder so that whenever a request is being executed in postman, it travels through Jmeter via proxy.

Answer (score 1):

1. Please check both the requests(Postman and jmeter) are same with all the values header and content type.
2. Check “Use multipart/form-data for POST” box is not selected.

> Use a multipart/form-data or application/x-www-form-urlencoded post
>   request

Reference;-https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request

For more information, please check this [blog.](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-advanced-rest-api-file-uploads-jmeter)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you're, like me, were trying to send a file and a JSON in the body togeter to some endpoint, then you should ***NOT*** put your JSON into request body, as when you don't send files. Instead, leave **Body data** field empty, use the **parameters** tab of **Http request / Basic** tab, and enter your JSON property name, as it is expected by server, put `application/json` into **Content-type** and ***DON'T*** check **URL encode?**.

This is because when you send files, the HTTP request body is used for both your JSON and file data. They're separated by a "boundary string" and both of them must have a name for a server to understand which's where.

Sorry for a bit of necroposting, but this is the only meaningful result I met while googling for "jmeter send file with body".

Comment: Hello apollov, do you have a screenshot? Thanks.

Comment: @jumping_monkey https://snipboard.io/1FHQUx.jpg https://snipboard.io/xotqM5.jpg